# SSIS Package from file system leads to login error but runs when deployed in SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I reference my SSIS Package (containing an OLEDB connection manager) in the SQL Server Agent from the file system, it returns a "Login failed for user 'SYS\SVC.SQL', which is the SQL Agent's service account.

The same package works fine when I deploy it into the SSISDB. The Package is set to "Don´t save sensitive" and SYS\SVC.SQL connects with Windows Authentication.

Where is the difference?

Comment: Where are the packages stored? Though why use the *old* File System deployment method anyway? SSISDB is vastly more versatile.

Comment: When you run it from the SSISDB, is it also run from a SQL Agent job or are you right clicking the package to run?

Comment: I start it by right clicking the Agent job and selecting "Start with step".

Comment: @Larnu I tried it from the file system, since my VS 2019 crashes, the moment I try to deploy it on the server :(